# Preload images asynchronously into the browser cache when the image has to be generated on the server first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, preloading

been reading stackoverflow for a couple years now, but never posted. Until today - ran into an issue I could not solve by myself and did not find a solution for.

The scenario: I have a dynamic webpage which basically shows screenshots of websites. These screenshots are generated on the fly for every new user and their URLs change. I want to preload these images into the browser cache so they're available in 0ms once the user clicks on a link. I don't want the subjective load time of the page increased, so they have to be loaded invisibly in the background.

My approach:
I used jelastic as my infrastructure to be able to scale later, then installed centOS with nginx, PHP and PhantomJS. I use PHP to query phantomJS to make the screenshots:

> exec ("phantomjs engine.js ".$source." ".$filez. " > /dev/null &");

The dev/null is used to not increase the load time to the user. 
I output the links to the browser. So far it works. Now I want to preload these images:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {   
    imgArray[i] = new Image(1,1);
    imgArray[i].visibility = 'hidden';
    imgArray[i].src = (document.links[i].href.substr(7) + ".png");              
    document.links[i].href = 'javascript: showtouser("' + imgArray[i].src.substr(7) + '");';
}
```

Two things I proably did wrong here:

- I start the image preloading before the images are generated on the server. I haven't found a way to start the caching only once the image has been generated by phantomJS. Onload event obviously does not work here.
- I think my approach is not really async and it would increase the subjective loading time felt by the user

What am I doing wrong? I'm an ISP guy, I suck at javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

You're approach was async. What you needed was a mechanism to identify image that didn't load, and retry.

This script will preload images, retry if failed, and hide links of images that don't exist even after retries ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xx2qL1c9/5/)):

```
var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.links, 0); // Converting links to a normal array

links.forEach(prepareImageLink);

function prepareImageLink(link) {
    var retries = 3; // current image number of retries
    var image = new Image();

    /** option: hide all links then reveal those with preloaded image
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 

    image.onload = function() {
        link.style.visibility = '';
    };
    **/

    image.onerror = function() {
        if(retries === 0) {
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // hide the link if image doesn't exist
           //link.remove(); // option - remove the link if image doesn't exist
            return;
        }

        retries--;

        setTimeout(function() {
            image.src = image.src + '?' + Date.now(); // for image to reload by adding the current dateTime to url
        }, 1000); // the amount of time to wait before retry, change it to fit you're system

    };

    image.src = (link.href + ".png"); // add .substr(7) in your case

    /** This is instead of 'javascript: showtouser("' + imgArray[i].src.substr(7) + '");'; which won't work on some browsers **/

    link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        document.getElementById('image').src = image.src; // change to your showtouser func
    });
}
```